# Convert Excel WorkBook To Bytes and attach in workitem

Tags: c#

In the following code lines i am trying to attach excel file to my work item with adding values for Worksheet cells, but my code lines are not fetching the excel work book bytes to attach. Please help me in this regard, Thanks in advance
JsonPatchDocument jsonPatchOperations = new JsonPatchDocument();

```
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var excelStream = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                
                var wrkBook = excelStream.Workbooks.Add(1);
                var wrkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wrkBook.Sheets[1];

                wrkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "NAME";
         
                var stringBytes = wrkBook.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
                

                await stream.WriteAsync(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length);

                stream.Position = 0;

                //var csvFile = new ExcelF
                var attachmentresult = targetWrkItemclient.CreateAttachmentAsync(stream, fileName: "test.csv").Result;
```

JsonPatchDocument jsonPatchOperations = new JsonPatchDocument();

```
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var excelStream = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                
                var wrkBook = excelStream.Workbooks.Add(1);
                var wrkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wrkBook.Sheets[1];

                wrkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "NAME";
         
                var stringBytes = wrkBook.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
                

                await stream.WriteAsync(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length);

                stream.Position = 0;

                //var csvFile = new ExcelF
                var attachmentresult = targetWrkItemclient.CreateAttachmentAsync(stream, fileName: "test.csv").Result;
```

Comment: I have found the solution myself, Thanks